# C# ConcurrentDictionary conditional Add

Tags: c#, synchronization, concurrentdictionary

I am trying to use ConcurrentDictionary to implement a cap limited cache. When the cache reaches its capacity, further additions of new items are rejected. The code snippet is as follows:

```
var result = this.cache.AddOrUpdate(
    key, 
    (key1) =>
    {
        if (!this.IsFull())
        {
            return new List<MyObject> { value };
        }

        what to return here??
    },
    (key1, value1) => 
    {
        value1.Add(value);

        return value1;
    });
```

My question here if the cache is full what should I return here? null? or what?

Comment: You could throw an exception I guess.  Or move the `IsFull` check out before the `AddOrUpdate`.

Comment: Should be noted that according to the [documentaiont](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentDictionary_2_AddOrUpdate__0_System_Func__0__1__System_Func__0__1__1__) the add an update delegates are called outside of locks so you might want to write your own code to do this including locking

Comment: Can I wrap the two delegates inside lock(this) { …} ?

Comment: It's best to always create an object just for locking and not use something like `lock(this)`.  Also `AddOrUpdate` will have some locking but the delegates are called outside of it.  So it would be best if you're locking included all the code and just don't use `AddOrUpdate`.  And really at that point you could even use a regular dictionary since you'll be handling the thread safety yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options:

- Write a new concurrrent data struct to manage your cache constraints. This is harder but if such a struct is going to be used in several places within your solution thet go for this one.
- Delegate cache's constraints management to the class that actually holds the cache. This is easier.

@Kirill Polishchuck answer is an example of the second alternative, but I belive it is not threadsafe so I would change it like so it ends up like:

```
if (!this.IsFull())
{
    // your logic here
    this.cache.AddOrUpdate(key, k=> new List<MyObject> { value };);
}
else
{
     // logic
}
```

For the first alternative here is a sample of what you could do to implement it. We implement `IDictonary<TKey,TValue>` interface and we lock on those operations that require so. Also, the class does not allow further insertions if `_maxCount` has been surpassed:

```
public class MaxCountDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary;
    private readonly object _lock;

    public MaxCountDictionary(int maxCount) : this(maxCount, EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default) { }

    public MaxCountDictionary(int maxCount, IEqualityComparer<TKey> equalityComparer)
    {
        _lock = new object();
        MaxCount = maxCount;
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(equalityComparer);
    }

    public int MaxCount { get; }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator() => _dictionary.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) => Add(item.Key, item.Value);

    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _dictionary.Clear();
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>) _dictionary).Contains(item);
        }
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>) _dictionary).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) => Remove(item.Key);

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                return _dictionary.Count;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly => ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>) _dictionary).IsReadOnly;

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return _dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
        }
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_dictionary.Count < MaxCount) _dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return _dictionary.Remove(key);
        }
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return _dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                return _dictionary[key];
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(key) || _dictionary.Count < MaxCount) _dictionary[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                return _dictionary.Keys.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    public ICollection<TValue> Values
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                return _dictionary.Values.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddOrUpdate(TKey key, TValue value, Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> updateValueFactory)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
                _dictionary[key] = updateValueFactory(key, value);
            else if (_dictionary.Count < MaxCount) _dictionary[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

With this other alternative you simply pass a MaxCount parameter to your collection, you can change it to accept a `Func<bool>` so that the dictionary can figure out whether to add more items or not, this way you can pass your `IsFull` method to it.

**Beware:** This is demo code, it is just a sample, it is not thread safe to enumarate, adjust it to your needs.